# ArcGIS Server - Map features received from html forms

Tags: arcgis-server, html

I would like to know if there is a way to send features data, such x and y coordinates and attributes properties, by a html form to ArcGIS Server in order to generate a map of these features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've [published a Feature Service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/publishing-feature-services.htm), you should be able to use the [AddFeatures operation in the REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/fsadd.html).